# Qual è il senso di "usare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, verbs

Nel racconto *Argon* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Nona Fina abitava a Carmagnola, in un alloggio al primo piano, e faceva splendidi ricami all’uncinetto. A sessantott'anni ebbe un lieve malore, una caôdaña, come allora **usavano** le signore, ed oggi misteriosamente non **usano** piú: da allora, per vent'anni e cioè fino alla sua morte, non uscí piú dalla sua camera; al sabato, dal balconcino pieno di gerani, fragile ed esangue salutava con la mano la gente che usciva da «scòla».

Dovete sapere che in questo racconto l'autore usa molti termini piemontesi o che appartengono al gergo degli ebrei del Piemonte, come  "caôdaña" o "scòla" (la scelta della grafia è  spiegata dal proprio Levi alla fine del racconto). Per esempio, lo scrittore  menziona che "scòla" era il termine che si adoperava per designare la sinagoga in questo gergo.

Dal contesto, posso capire che si sta facendo riferimento a qualcosa (questi lievi malori) che accadeva alle signore in passato, ma che, nel momento della narrazione, non accade più. Tuttavia, guardando alla [voce "usare" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/usare), non riesco a vedere a quale accezione possa corrispondere l'uso che se ne fa nel brano sopra citato. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Il senso è lo stesso di “essere solito”.

Comment: @egreg:   Quindi, è lo stesso uso che si fa negli esempi "uso uscire la sera per fare una breve passeggiata" o "i Romani usavano tributare ai loro imperatori onori divini"? Cioè, le signore avevano in passato la consuetudine di "avere malori" e, in quel momento, non avevano più quella abitudine? Non si tratta di  una consuetudine un po' strana?

Answer (score 2):

Il senso è “essere solito”, come da dizionario.

Nel particolare contesto è adoperato un modo ironico: un tempo le signore usavano avere le scalmane (tipico sintomo della menopausa), oggi non usano più. Il senso è che un tempo non se ne vergognavano, oggi sì.

Comment: Ma, come ho detto nel commento precedente, "essere solito qualcosa" non significa "avere questo qualcosa come consuetudine"?

Comment: @Charo Certo, ma se non riesci a vedere il senso ironico…

Comment: Ah, OK, @egreg: può darsi che questo sia stato il problema: c'è in certo modo uno scherzo nella frase che io non avevo capito.

Comment: Segnalo che le parole "caôdaña" e "scòla" non appartengono strettamente al gergo degli ebrei, ma sono termini del dialetto piemontese. Aggiungo per @Charo che la "ñ" si pronuncia come nella parola francese "en", e non come in quella spagnola señora.

Comment: @enrico Grazie. Ho tradotto con “scalmana” che è il termine usato nella mia regione; potrebbe essere anche “vampa”.

Comment: Sì, @enrico, questo lo dice Levi nel racconto: la spiegazione comincia con la frase: "Poiché il gergo descritto è ibrido, ibrida è anche la grafia a cui ho dovuto ricorrere". E poi spiega la pronuncia dei diversi segni scelti. Ecco un brano del racconto: "mentre la sinagoga, con orgogliosa modestia, veniva detta semplicemente «scòla», il luogo dove si impara e si viene educati, e, parallelamente, il rabbino non veniva designato col termine proprio «rabbi» o «rabbénu» (nostro rabbi), ma come Morénô (nostro maestro), o Khakhàm (il Sapiente)". Con "gergo" si riferisce a questo tipo de cose.

Comment: @enrico: Ho modificato leggermente il testo della domanda. Spero che adesso vada meglio. Grazie della segnalazione.